# Shell/AWK - Its not displaying the values, and how to add reg exp

Tags: regex, linux, perl, unix, awk

I have a small issue, the code below was working fine but now its not displaying nothing, i dont quite understand where is the error for this.

```
> #! /bin/bash

awk -F, '       FILENAME = $1 { FS = ":" }

        { print $1 " "  $2 " "  $3 " " $4 }





                '
```

- I would like to add some options like: ./search thefile -C

i want that the reg ex -C to be like an option and display some specific things.

Any ideas about this ?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you started . . .

If the file test.dat looks like this

```
100:200:300:400
```

Then this shell script will print each of those values.

```
#! /bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN { FS = ":" } NF==4 && $0 ~/:/{ print FILENAME, $1 " "  $2 " "  $3 " " $4 }' $1
```

Invoke the shell script "test.sh" with a single-quoted argument, as

```
./test.sh 'test*.dat'
```

The test `NF>=4` makes sure there are at least four fields before trying to print. The regex match `$0~/:/` makes sure the line has at least one colon. (There's probably a better way to express what you're trying to do.)

The `FILENAME` variable tells you which file the row comes from. You might be able to delete it after you're confident things are working as you intended.

Comment: Hi,

What about the functions like thescript -C  i mean -C how can i do this ?

Comment: @user1253622: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't want to do:

```
FILENAME = $1
```

You probably meant

```
FILENAME == $1
```

Beyond that, the script doesn't really make sense without some context including sample input and expected output.